# How to position buttons on story board for all devices in xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I'm trying to place these buttons that are responsive for all the devices. Can someone please help me? I've been trying this but never worked. attached screen shot for what i'm looking- [image: storyboard]Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try these constraints.  You can adjust the constant values to get the look you want:

Top button:

1. Button.Leading equal to Superview.Leading.
2. Button.Top equal to Top Layout Guide.Bottom with constant `25`.
3. Superview.Trailing equal to Button.Trailing with constant `70`.
4. Button.Height equal to constant `140`.

Middle button:

1. Button.Leading equal to Superview.Leading with constant `70`.
2. Button.Top equal to FirstButton.Bottom with constant `35`.
3. Superview.Trailing equal to Button.Trailing.

Bottom button:

1. Button.Leading equal to Superview.Leading.
2. Button.Top equal to SecondButton.Bottom with constant `35`.
3. Superview.Trailing equal to Button.Trailing with constant `70`.
4. Bottom Layout Guide.Top equal to Button.Bottom with constant `45`.
5. Button.Height equal to constant `140`.

This will allow the middle button to grow in height on larger devices, and all buttons will grow in width on larger devices.

Comment: thanks.. I got an idea how things work! thanks much again!!